# Why Post Build action doesn't overwrite the build status in Jenkins?

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am working on a Jenkins job which has a Time-out with 1 retry. If the time-out is expired the build status will be `ABORTED` and the `Naginator` plugin will retry the build.

**Abort the build if it's stuck:**

[image: timeout]

I have written a very simple shell script into an execute shell box to test the time-out mechanism.

**Execute shell:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "START"
sleep 60
echo "1 min"
sleep 60
echo "2 min"
sleep 60
echo "3 min"
sleep 60
echo "4 min"
sleep 60
echo "5 min"
sleep 60
echo "6 min"
sleep 60
echo "7 min"
sleep 60
echo "8 min"
sleep 60
echo "9 min"
sleep 60
echo "10 min"
sleep 60
echo "11 min"
sleep 60
echo "12 min"
sleep 60
echo "13 min"
echo "STOP"
```

And I have a `Post build action` where I want to detect the retried builds. I am using the `NAGINATOR_COUNT` environment variable which is set only if the re-trigger has already been happened. This script works as expected. And I have set the `Escalate script execution status to job status` option, it means the status of the `Post build action` should be overwrite the "original" build status. I have had several tries and it works in case of `SUCCESS -> FAILURE` but it doesn't work in case of `ABORTED -> FAILURE`.

**Post build task:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "START POST BUILD TASK"
export NAGINATOR_COUNT=${NAGINATOR_COUNT:-NO_RETRY}

echo "NAGINATOR_COUNT=${NAGINATOR_COUNT}"

if [[ ${NAGINATOR_COUNT} -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "NAGINATOR_COUNT variable is 1. Retry was happened"
    exit 1
fi

echo  "NAGINATOR_COUNT variable is NOT 1. Retry wasn't happened"
```

**Output of NON re-triggered job:**

```
2020-02-21 07:40:49 [test_job] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins5602046862350636731.sh
2020-02-21 07:40:49 START
2020-02-21 07:41:49 1 min
2020-02-21 07:42:49 2 min
2020-02-21 07:43:49 Scheduled restart of the build (up to 1 times).
2020-02-21 07:43:49 Build timed out (after 3 minutes). Marking the build as aborted.
2020-02-21 07:43:49 /tmp/jenkins5602046862350636731.sh: line 8: 14915 Terminated              sleep 60
2020-02-21 07:43:49 3 min
2020-02-21 07:43:49 
Build was aborted
2020-02-21 07:43:49 Performing Post build task...
2020-02-21 07:43:49 Match found for :Build timed out : True
2020-02-21 07:43:49 Logical operation result is TRUE
2020-02-21 07:43:49 Running script  : #!/bin/bash
2020-02-21 07:43:49 [test_job] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins3154001743586365902.sh
2020-02-21 07:43:49 START POST BUILD TASK
2020-02-21 07:43:49 NAGINATOR_COUNT=NO_RETRY
2020-02-21 07:43:49 NAGINATOR_COUNT variable is NOT 1. Retry wasn't happened
2020-02-21 07:43:50 POST BUILD TASK : SUCCESS
2020-02-21 07:43:50 END OF POST BUILD TASK : 0
2020-02-21 07:43:50 No emails were triggered.
2020-02-21 07:43:50 Finished: ABORTED
```

**Output ofre-triggered job:**

```
2020-02-21 07:43:50 [test_job] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins1787517070120788068.sh
2020-02-21 07:43:50 START
2020-02-21 07:44:50 1 min
2020-02-21 07:45:52 2 min
2020-02-21 07:46:50 Scheduled restart of the build (up to 1 times).
2020-02-21 07:46:50 Build timed out (after 3 minutes). Marking the build as aborted.
2020-02-21 07:46:50 /tmp/jenkins1787517070120788068.sh: line 8: 15179 Terminated              sleep 60
2020-02-21 07:46:50 3 min
2020-02-21 07:46:50 
Build was aborted
2020-02-21 07:46:50 Performing Post build task...
2020-02-21 07:46:50 Match found for :Build timed out : True
2020-02-21 07:46:50 Logical operation result is TRUE
2020-02-21 07:46:50 Running script  : #!/bin/bash
2020-02-21 07:46:50 [test_job] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins218780675757116076.sh
2020-02-21 07:46:50 START POST BUILD TASK
2020-02-21 07:46:50 NAGINATOR_COUNT=1
2020-02-21 07:46:50 NAGINATOR_COUNT variable is 1. Retry was happenned
2020-02-21 07:46:50 POST BUILD TASK : FAILURE
2020-02-21 07:46:50 END OF POST BUILD TASK : 0
2020-02-21 07:46:50 ESCALATE FAILED POST BUILD TASK TO JOB STATUS
2020-02-21 07:46:50 No emails were triggered.
2020-02-21 07:46:50 Finished: ABORTED
```

**Editable Email Notification trigger section:**

[image: mail_config]

As you can see in case of re-triggered build it seems everything is correct and it should overwrite the `ABORTED` status to `FAILURE` status. But it finished with `ABORTED` status.

**Reason:**

I need this mechanism because I want to send a notification E-mail in the Post build section BUT only if the re-triggered build failed. It means the Notification mail is triggered only by `FAILURE` status (`ABORTED` is not allowed to trigger the mail). So this is the reason why I want to change the `ABORTED` status to `FAILURE` status if the re-triggered build has been failed.